# Why does Indy Project HttpClient Get() give code 500 on some URLs which work fine in web browsers?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have several URLs which work just fine in all browsers, but if I try to get the page content using Get() of the Indy Http client, it returns error code 500, internal server error. This is with the latest Indy SVN build (4981).

Here is my example code. All that is needed for this is Delphi with Indy components and a form with a button and a memo.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var HTTPCLIENT1: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
   try
     HTTPCLIENT1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
     Memo1.Clear;
     with HTTPCLIENT1 do
     begin
          HandleRedirects := True;
          Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i586; en-US; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20040924 Epiphany/1.4.4 (Ubuntu)';
          Memo1.Text := Get('http://www.laredoute.fr/vente-machine-a-coudre-bernette-20-kit-couture--garantie-2-ans.aspx?productid=401225048&documentid=999999&categoryid=22918417&customertarget=0&offertype=0&prodcolor=1#pos=33_n_n_n_n_n_n&numberpage=2');
          Caption := ResponseText;
     end;
   except
     On e: Exception do
     begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception: '+e.Message);
     end;
   end;
  finally
     HTTPCLIENT1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

It's not a connection problem on my side, since 99% of URLs return 200 or 404, only few return 500, but every browser opens them fine in a second.

Comment: Are there redirections happening on the URLs that fail?

Comment: Totally irrelevant, but your useragent string (Gecko 1.7.3, which was used in Firefox 0.10) may trigger some websites to try to deliver different content (suitable for older browsers).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That kind of failure usually suggests the `GET` request is malformed in some way, causing the server code to fail on its end.  But without seeing what the webbrowser requests actually look like for comparison to TIdHTTP's requests, there is no way to know for sure what the server is not liking.

**Update**: what I see happening is that when a webbrowser requests the URL, the server sends back a 200 response immediately, however when TIdHTTP requests the URL, the server sends a 301 redirect to a new URL, which then sends a 302 redirect to an error page when TIdHTTP requests that URL, which then sends the 500 response when TIdHTTP requests that URL.

The two differences between a webbrowser request and the initial TIdHTTP request that would have an effect on a webserver are:

1. the URL you are requesting with TIdHTTP includes an anchor tag at the end (everything after the `#` character - `#pos=33_n_n_n_n_n_n&numberpage=2`) which webbrowsers would normally strip out.  Anchors are not actually part of URLs. They are meant for webbrowsers to use when locating spots within data that is retrieved from a URL.
2. the user agent.  Some web servers are sensitive to different user agents, and can send different responses to different types of user agents.

When I remove the anchor from the URL, TIdHTTP.Get() no longer crashes:

```
Memo1.Text := Get('http://www.laredoute.fr/vente-machine-a-coudre-bernette-20-kit-couture--garantie-2-ans.aspx?productid=401225048&documentid=999999&categoryid=22918417&customertarget=0&offertype=0&prodcolor=1');
```

Comment: I've just tested 3 more browsers, 2 mobile ones and a very old VM with IE6. The URL has displayed just fine. If my code is fine, is this maybe an Indy bug?

Comment: I thought Indy parses out anchors before doing any request, does it not?

Comment: It does not currently strip out anchors from URLs. That thought occurred to me a few minutes ago. TIdHTTP should be doing that, so I will update it shortly.

Comment: Actually, after a code review, it is supposed to strip the anchors after all. It is actually a bug in `TIdURI` where the anchor is ending up at the end of the `TIdURI.Params` property instead of being in the `TIdURI.Bookmark` property, where it belongs. When I fixed that, your original code worked fine as-is.

Comment: thanks! is this commited to SVN already? Which Indy revision do I need for this fix?

Comment: I just now commited it to SVN, revision 4985.