# Why does this web server return code 404 for Indy, but code 200 for every browser?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have one URLs that works just fine in all browsers (5 tested on 2 computers), but if I try to get the page content using Get() of the Indy Http client, it returns error code 404, page not found. This is with the latest Indy SVN build (4985).

**Why does this web server return code 404 for Indy, but code 200 for every browser?**

*I suspect this may be a bug in Indy because of the "#" character in the URL (Indy cuts everything off after #). If so, is there any way to work-around this. Maybe replace the # char with escape code?*

Here is my example code. All that is needed for this is Delphi with Indy components and a form with a button and a memo.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var HTTPCLIENT1: TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
   try
     HTTPCLIENT1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
     Memo1.Clear;
     with HTTPCLIENT1 do
     begin
          HandleRedirects := True;
          Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31';
          Memo1.Text := Get('http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/#/2011/scor/');
          Caption := ResponseText;
     end;
   except
     On e: Exception do
     begin
          Memo1.Lines.Add('Exception: '+e.Message);
     end;
   end;
  finally
     HTTPCLIENT1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: According to [the answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935811/why-does-indy-project-httpclient-get-give-code-500-on-some-urls-which-work-fin#comment22707608_15936205), revision 4985 was supposed to resolve that issue. Are you sure you've installed it correctly? Have you used WireShark to compare what browsers send with what your program sends?

Comment: I agree with Rob. I fixed that bug so `#` and everything after it would not be sent to the server anymore. I will double check again, but it was definately working correctly last time.

Comment: @RobKennedy this is another issue. The other post was about getting error code 500 with a anchor within an URL. this was fixed. This issue is about getting code 404 without an anchor withint the URL.

Comment: @Casady: Like Rob said, you should be using Wireshark, or other packet sniffer, to diagnose problems like that. Your earlier problem was caused by Indy sending a different URL than browsers send, leading to a series of redirects that ultimately failed on the server end. This problem is likely similar. So you need to make sure Indy is actually sending the same URL that browsers send.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right. This problem is similar but not the same, For some reason Indy does not strip the anchor from the URL, even in build 4985.

Comment: @Casady: There is no "logical" anchor in the URL you are trying to access, but tbere is a "physical" one in it because you did not pre-encode the URL before passing it to TIdHTTP. You must do that, it is a requirement. If it is not working correctly, then something else is wrong. I will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>`#` is a reserved character in URLs.  If you want to use reserved characters inside of a URL, you need to url-encode them.  `TIdHTTP` does not do that for you.  It requires you to pass in an **encoded** URL, but you are passing in an **unencoded** URL instead.  Since `#` is unencoded, it gets treated as an anchor and stripped off, so you are actually requesting `http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/`, hense the 404 reply.</strike>

`#` is url-encoded as `%23`, so use this:

```
Memo1.Text := Get('http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/%23/2011/scor/');
```

Or this:

```
Memo1.Text := Get(TIdURI.URLEncode('http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/#/2011/scor/'));
```

**Update:** I tracked down the problem. It is another `TIdURI` parsing bug, this time related to having a `/` character after the `#` character.  `TIdURI` checks for `/` characters before it checks for a `#` character, so the anchor portion of the URL was ending up in the `TIdURI.Path` property (previously it was ending up in the `TIdURI.Params` property) and thus submitted to the server.  I have checked in a new fix (SVN rev 4987).

Comment: http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/%23/2011/scor/ does not work with Indy, nor in a web browser.

Comment: You are not supposed to give a webbrowser an encoded URL, it encodes it during transmission. TIdHTTP expects pre-encoded URLs. I will have to test the URL when i get a chance, but it should be working fine if the original unencoded url works in a browser. They are equivilent. Again, please validate with a packet sniffer to make sure what TIdHTTP sends matches what a webbrowser sends.

Comment: I've installed WireShark, and Chrome strips everything from # on, as Indy should, but it does not. I assume there is still an anchor bug in Indy that is not fixed by #4985

Comment: @Casady: Since you now have Wireshark, please update your question to show the actual HTTP requests that webbrowsers and TIdHTTP are actually sending so we can see the differences. TIdHTTP does correct strip out `#` anchors now, so the problem is something else.

Comment: @Casady: when you give `http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/#/2011/scor/` to a webbrowser, it gets encoded as `/gpi-data/%23/2011/scor/` when sent to the server. When you give `http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/#/2011/scor/` to TIdHTTP, it gets treated as-is and sent to the server as `/gpi-data/`, which is why you get the 404. That is why you must make sure any URL you give to TIdHTTP is pre-encoded so TIdHTTP parses it correctly.

Comment: /gpi-data/ does not give 404, it gives 200.

Comment: @Casady: I have found the bug, I will check in a fix shortly.

Comment: @Casady: the fix is now checked in.

Answer (score 3):

Your suspicion is correct. You've included the `#` section of the address in your request. Browsers don't do that because that section is reserved for *in-page* navigation. The server doesn't know that, so it tries to fetch the resource that corresponds to the *full* URL you gave it, including the `#` and everything afterward. Nothing matches, so it fails with status 404.

Either do as the browsers do and strip that section from the URL prior to sending the request to the server, or update Indy to revision 4987 so that it will happen automatically. Merely escaping the character will continue to yield status 404.

Comment: SVN revision 4985 fixed a bug in TIdURI that was not properly stripping off `#...` if present. You don't need to strip it off manually. I agree with Rob's comment that 4985 was likely not installed correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau 4985 is correctly installed, as the old issue IS fixed on my system. The old issue was a URL with an anchor that gave 200 with the browsers, but 500 with Indy. #4985 fixed that and it gives 200 with indy. But with the new URL (http://www.visionofhumanity.org/gpi-data/#/2011/scor/) and Build #4985 Indy gives 404, but browsers give 200. I've opened a new question, because the issue is not 100% related to the issue fixed before.

Comment: @RobKennedy "Do as the browsers do and strip that section from the URL prior to sending the request to the server. Merely escaping the character will continue to yield status 404." Why should I strip anything? Indy does it by itself! The #4985 build fixed an issue with incorrectly stripped anchors, but this is a new issue.

Comment: If you strip the anchor portion, does the link work? Seems like a basic thing to test. Also, I urge you to use Wire Shark to do some debugging of your own. It can show you exactly what request your program sends over the wire. Compare it to what some browsers send. When you see what's different, you can use that information to investigate you problem.